# BIRT chart using birt:report tag

Tags: birt

I have tried to create charts with birt:viewer tag which displays viewer in iframe. But I want to use birt:report tag which will display inside div. I gone through

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage2.2.php#tags

viewer tag library. Can someone help me with a sample ?

Answer (score 0):

use `reportcontainer="div"` attribute in birt reporter tag then our charts generate on div

Comment: Please elaborate more your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this tag**

```
<birt:report id="<%=repoviewid %>" reportDesign="testreport.rptdesign" height="200" format="html" reportContainer="div" scrolling="no"/>
```